# HealthKit: HKObserverQuery not Firing

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm trying to do a pretty basic thing: set up an HKObserverQuery so I can know when various data points are changed (I've made sure that the user has authorized the app to use the data point in question.) For whatever reason, I can get the query to fire every time the app is launched, but it does not fire when I close the app, go into the Health app, and manually update the data point. I've done a fair amount of searching and haven't been able to successfully use the code that others have posted, code that they say works for them.

I'm two weeks into Cocoa/Objective C development, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see what it is. Any guidance here would be great, even if it's just advice on debugging. Since the app itself is closed and I'm not getting anything that it might log out in the console, I don't really have any visibility into what's happening.

The code that I'm using for the observer query is below:

```
   HKQuantityType *heartRate = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];
    [self.healthStore enableBackgroundDeliveryForType:heartRate frequency:HKUpdateFrequencyImmediate withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"observing heart rate");
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bodbot.com/Scripts/wearable_heartrate_changed.php"]];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"FAILED observing heart rate");
        }
    }];
    HKObserverQuery *query = [[HKObserverQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:heartRate predicate:nil updateHandler:^(HKObserverQuery *query, HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler completionHandler, NSError *error) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bodbot.com/Scripts/wearable_heartrate_changed.php"]];
    }];

    [self.healthStore executeQuery:query];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have found, empirically (not from documentation), that the Observer Query does NOT fire when running in the simulator but it DOES fire when running on device. And I do not have the background modes capability turned on.

Answer (score -1):

When you suspend an app on iOS, by default it stops running unless it has taken a [background task assertion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:) or has a [background mode entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW17).  The app cannot receive notifications when it is not running.  HealthKit has a feature which can wake your app in the background when there are new samples of a particular type, though.  See the [Managing Background Delivery](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014708-CH1-DontLinkElementID_28) documentation for HKHealthStore.  Use that in conjunction with HKObserverQuery to be notified whenever there is new data, even when your app is not already running.

Comment: Thanks for this! One thing that I was not doing is enable "Background Modes" as an app capability (although I did not check any specific background modes as none of them seem to apply); I currently am using enableBackgroundDeliveryForType as per the documentation you linked to. I ended up doing this, but still cannot get the query to fire when there is a new data point. Is it possible that I'm missing something else?

Comment: @tshortli, if you don't mine, can you do a sample which will wake up the application in background(earlier killed application forcedly) when new health data available?

Comment: @tshortli, I tried this on my application and failed(Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29142367/1295573 ).  So that only I am asking you...:-)

Comment: Don't enable Background Modes unless your app actually requires them.  I only referred to them to give an example of how your app may gain the ability to run in the background.

Comment: The code to enable background delivery of HealthKit data looks correct to me.  You should file a bug with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com to get more help diagnosing the issue.  Examining the Console logs and looking for any suspicious messages is the next step I would take.

Comment: I haven't seen anything in console logs yet (there isn't any indication of errors with the observer query). If it isn't too much trouble, as per Bhanu's comment, a sample app of healthkit's background querying working would be great; it might help me track down where I'm screwing up. No worries if that's too much trouble, I just haven't been able to find such a sample app anywhere else :)