# How do I initialize a HKObserverQuery with updateHandler?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm trying to learn `Apple HealthKit`, and my current goal is to make my application observe HK queries for certain sample types while it's in the background. I can initialize an observerquery with sampletype and predicate:

```
let query = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: nil) {...}
```

But when I try to use a custom updateHandler in initialization, XCode raises an issue:

```
func setUpBackgroundDelivery() {

    guard let sampleType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose) as HKSampleType! else {
        ...
    }

    self.healthKitStore.enableBackgroundDeliveryForType(sampleType, frequency: .Immediate) { (success, error) in
        ...
    }

    let updateHandler: (HKObserverQuery, HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler, NSError?) -> Void = {
        query, completionHandler, error in
        ...
        NSLog("HealthKit Background Delivery received")
        completionHandler()
    }

    let query = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: nil, updateHandler: updateHandler) {
        query, completionHandler, error in
        ...
        completionHandler()   
    }
    healthKitStore.executeQuery(query)
}
```

**Issue being:**

> *...'(sampleType: HKSampleType, predicate: _, updateHandler: (HKObserverQuery, HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler, NSError?) -> Void,
>   (_, _, _) -> ())' (aka '(sampleType: HKSampleType, predicate: _,
>   updateHandler: (HKObserverQuery, () -> (), Optional) -> (),
>   (_, _, _) -> ())') is not convertible to '(sampleType: HKSampleType,
>   predicate: NSPredicate?, updateHandler: (HKObserverQuery,
>   HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler, NSError?) -> Void)' (aka
>   '(sampleType: HKSampleType, predicate: Optional,
>   updateHandler: (HKObserverQuery, () -> (), Optional) ->
>   ())'), tuples have a different number of elements*

Comment: A long time ago I answer a question related with backgrounds notifications and `HKObserverQuery`, I think you can benefit a lot from it and from the other answer provided with a detailed explanation of the times of update and more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375767/healthkit-background-delivery-when-app-is-not-running

Comment: I think I have misunderstood the syntax. Seems like if I include the updateHandler argument, I'm going to have to remove the following closures. Thanks for the comment, it helped me to realize this.

Answer (score 1):

You should not specify both `updateHandler` and a trailing closure. Only one of them can be the argument for the update handler block parameter of the initializer.