# Active my app when user walked 1 km and then 5km and so on. by using healthkit in ios swift when app is not running or in background

Tags: ios, swift3, healthkit

I have followed the answers of this question -
 [Healthkit background delivery when app is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375767/healthkit-background-delivery-when-app-is-not-running) 
on stackoverflow but not achieved my goal.

I want to notify user using local notification when he/she walked 1 km exact, when app is in background and not running state.
I am still not able to read the distance from Healthkit in background as well.

But when app is in foreground then only my code works and the code is as blow

```
let healthKitStore = HKHealthStore()
    let distanceType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)!
    let query:HKObserverQuery = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: distanceType, predicate: nil) { (query, HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler, error) in
        //here I schedule my local notification
        // I want to read the distance here and also want to notify user.
        self.callLocalNotification(1)
        HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler()
    }
    healthKitStore?.execute(query)
    healthKitStore?.enableBackgroundDelivery(for: distanceType, frequency: .immediate, withCompletion: { (succeeded, error) in
        if succeeded{
            print("Enabled background delivery of Distance changes")
        } else {
            if let theError = error{
                print("Failed to enable background delivery of Distance changes.")
                print("Error = \(theError)")
            }
        }
    })

func callLocalNotification(_ distance:Int)
{
    // Request Notification Settings
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (notificationSettings) in
        switch notificationSettings.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            self.requestAuthorization(completionHandler: { (success) in
                guard success else { return }

                // Schedule Local Notification
                self.scheduleLocalNotification(distance)
            })
        case .authorized:
            // Schedule Local Notification
            self.scheduleLocalNotification(distance)
        case .denied:
            print("Application Not Allowed to Display Notifications")
        }
    }
```