# HKObserverQuery only runs when the application is reopened

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, background-fetch, hkobserverquery

So I've been following the instructions in this answer...
[Healthkit background delivery when app is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375767/healthkit-background-delivery-when-app-is-not-running/35073904#35073904)

The code runs fine and works whilst the application is open and says that background delivery is successful, however when I test the application by walking around and changing the clock on the device to an hour forward I do not receive any logs to let me know it has run. However, if I open the application again the observer query runs.

```
private func checkAuthorization(){
    let healthDataToRead = Set(arrayLiteral: self.distanceQuantityType!)


    healthKitStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: healthDataToRead) { (success, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            print("There was an error requesting Authorization to use Health App")
        }
        if success {
            print("success")

        }
    }

}
public func enableBackgroundDelivery() {

    self.checkAuthorization()
    self.healthKitStore.enableBackgroundDelivery(for: self.distanceQuantityType!, frequency: .hourly) { (success, error) in
        if success{
            print("Background delivery of steps. Success = \(success)")

        }

        if let error = error {
            print("Background delivery of steps failed = \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }



}

func observeDistance(_ handler:@escaping (_ distance: Double) -> Void) {

    let updateHandler: (HKObserverQuery?, HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler?, Error?) -> Void = { query, completion, error in
        if !(error != nil) {
            print("got an update")
            completion!()
        } else {
            print("observer query returned error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    let query = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: self.distanceQuantityType!, predicate: nil, updateHandler: updateHandler)
    self.healthKitStore.execute(query)
}
```

The query is initialised in the appDelegate method didFinishLaunching

Answer (score 0):

This particular HealthKitQuery is ***asynchronous.*** You should wait until it finishes processing.

However, this case is not possible in `didFinishLaunching`. The application just ended execution and there is not enough time to process the query.

I would seriously suggest to rethink the logic behind the operation of your code. A good way to solve this would be to put the request elsewhere, preferrably after the needed operations were completed.

Comment: According to the documentation the observer query should always be initialised in the didFinishLaunching.
I feel like there's some kind of error preventing the code from running in the background, as it works perfectly when the application is opened again.